# Angular 6 'data' become Undefined when refreshing the page

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am using angular 6 to develop a new web app.I am sending data from one component to another using a 'sharedservice'.I can send it very comfortably.
When i try to refresh the page the shared service data become undefined and app breaks. Of course i am tried with an if condition and it works perfectly,and app redirected to previous page;

But is there any other way rather than if condition,so the browser should stay in 'setupItemComponent' with previous data and shared data should not be an undefined one

Thanks in advance

here is my code:

```
setup.ts:
=================

constructor(private router:Router,private sharedservice:SharedService){}

onCLickEdit(clickedData:any){

//function will execute when button clicks
sharedservice.data=clickedData;
this.router.navigate(['setup/setup_items'])
}


setupItem.ts
====================

data:any;
constructor(private sharedservice:sharedService){}

ngOnInit() {
this.data = this.sharedData.data;
if (this.data) {
  this.formValidation();
}
else {
  this.router.navigate(['setup']);
}

}


 sharedService.ts
==================

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class ShareDataService {

data: any;

constructor() { }


}
```

Comment: Hi Pepe, I'm having this issue. Did you fix this issue?

Comment: Yeah,you can use the browser local storage

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work unless you use a database, to store the data and retrieve it on ngOnInit() every time, because everytime you refresh every value is reinitialized unless that data is hardcoded.

I suggest [Firebase](https://hackernoon.com/introduction-to-firebase-218a23186cd7) using [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

Comment: thank you!. can you please tell me how can i done with firebase?.Because i am currently using firebase

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md (scroll down and find Saving data, and more information about retrieving is also found on that page), you'll also find many good tutorials on their channel on youtube "Angular Firebase"

Comment: its about firebase,i think; but i am using firestore

Comment: Firestore is in Firebase. Firebase is a Backend as a Service (BaaS). Firestore is a database.

Comment: can you please tell me the difference between both?if so it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are going to lose the data you passed on when you refresh the page. In scenarios like this it is possible to store data locally within the user's browser by using Web Storage. Here i believe its better to take use of the session storage.

Your shared service could look like

```html
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ShareDataService {

  private data: any;

  constructor(private storage: SessionStorageService) {
  }

  public clearLocalStorage() {
    this.storage.clear('sharedData');
  }

  public setdata(data: any) {
    this.data = data;
    this.storage.store('sharedData', data);

  }

  public getdata() {
    return this.storage.retrieve('sharedData');
  }
}
```